# Log in with custom shell in new or existing VT

Tags: linux, bash, shell, session

Is it possible to completely create a new terminal just as the terminal we get when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2...F7</kbd> in Ubuntu?

I read about sessions creating daemons from sessions which  require no tty. So my question is can a new terminal not as a program in bash but a standalone program be created. If so please give me some reference which can help me  in accessing one of the 7 ttys present in the system. I already created a shell script but its working as a program under bash

Comment: What you do when your press Ctrl+Alt+FX is switch to (an already created) console. If you want to create a terminal in Ubuntu, just start `gnome-terminal` (from the (`bash`) command prompt or from a program)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: i need my own shell  to be created unlike running a program under bash i need a standalone terminal

Comment: @jackwilson: So you want to use one of the textual VTs and not a terminal window in your graphical environment? Do you want to log in and then start your shell instead of Bash or do you want that VT to run your shell right away without entering credentials (of course being a security no-go in a production environment)?

Comment: @michael jaros ya exactly as u said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [virtual terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_terminal) (VTs) accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> do not run a [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29). Instead they allow you to log in, usually  running the [`getty (8)` or `agetty(8)` program](http://linux.die.net/man/8/agetty) which will invoke [login(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/login) (or a graphical display manager like [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) which will start a graphical session).

Logging in interactively on a text console will start the shell defined for your user in `/etc/passwd`.

- So if you want to log in using your shell, e.g.
  `/usr/bin/bettershell`, the easiest way is to create a test user
  whose shell is set to your program:

  ```
  useradd -m -s /usr/bin/bettershell testuser
  passwd testuser
  ```

  You should now be able to test your shell by logging in with
  `testuser` from any text VT.
- If for some reason you want a VT to run your shell right away without
  the login procedure, you can replace the getty line for that VT in
  `/etc/inittab` with the path to your shell. Be warned that your shell
  will be run as `root` in that case and anyone with physical access to your machine will be able to use it without entering a password.